# Insert an array in the database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

I want to insert an array in the database. The array can be changed all the time. I want different rows in the database.

My code:

```
$var = file_get_contents("test2.txt");
   $test = preg_replace('/\\\\/', '', $var);
   $poep = explode(" ", $test);
```

Yeah, there is no database connection, because I want to know how to 'split' the array to insert it in the database.

I have tried this:

```
foreach($poep as $row) {
    $row   = $mysqli->real_escape_string($row);
    if($mysqli->query("insert into data('array') VALUES ($row)") == false){
        echo 'Doesnt works!';
    }
```

It returns 'Doesnt works', so I think there is a problem with query?

Comment: you want diferent rows in datebase or one row ?

Comment: I want different rows in the database.

Comment: Can you var_dump $poep and show some sample data from test2.txt? It looks to me like your code should do the trick, assuming the file's content is space-separated

Comment: @RoelHarbers putting it that way I can understand it

Comment: just save it in JSON or CSV (comma seperated values) format

Comment: @RoelHarbers, it outputs a lot.. (an array). I can not post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@NadirDev Hi. Assuming that you are using Core PHP programming. After exploding the string by the space, run foreach loop and then insert individual rows. Look at this rough code to get idea:

```
foreach($poep as $row) {
    // $row now contains one word. Add that in database.
    $row   = mysql_real_escape_string($row);
    $query = mysql_query("insert into tableName('fieldName') VALUES ($row)");
}
```

Comment: Suggesting those ancient, deprecated `mysql_*` functions?

Comment: Always use PDO now onwards @NadirDev and / or switch to better framework for data security.

Comment: Doesn't works.. It doesn't add anything in my database.

Comment: @NadirDev Yes, as from PHP 5.5 they are deprecated. That's why I am telling you to use PDO for specific DB class.

Comment: Which is fine. The essence of this answer: Loop through the array with a `foreach` loop and insert a single item within the loop, using your database library of choice.

Answer (score 0):

here's some code I wrote. It processes a CSV file and stores separate rows into a db table (difference is just that you have a TXT file). It does the mysql insertion in batches of 250 rows. Hope it can help you!

```
// read all input rows into an array
echo "Processing input..<br /><br />";
$row = 0;
$input = array();
if (($handle = fopen($file['tmp_name'], "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            $input[$row][] = addslashes($data[$c]);
        }

        $row++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

$count = 0;
$q = "INSERT INTO `inputs` (`keyword`, `percent`, `link`, `added_on`) VALUES ";

foreach ($input as $inp) {
    $q .= "('" . addslashes($inp[0]) . "', '" . addslashes($inp[1]) . "', '" . addslashes($inp[2]) . "', '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "'), ";
    $count++;

    if ($count >= 250) {
        $q = substr($q, 0, -2);
        $q = mysqli_query($con, $q);

        $q = "INSERT INTO `inputs` (`keyword`, `percent`, `link`, `added_on`) VALUES ";
        $count = 0;
    }
}

if ($count > 0) {
    $q = substr($q, 0, -2);
    $q = mysqli_query($con, $q);
}

echo "Successfully added " . count($input) . " rows to the input list.";
```